# Automatic take Screenshot in every 10 min

Tags: screenshot

There is some processes running on my pc,I want to take automatically screenshot of my desktop in every 10 min. Is any way to do this?

Comment: I am using Windos OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow the steps

```
Download Nircmd.exe and paste into c:/Windows/System32
Then make a bat file and paste the below script

@ echo off
Nircmd.exe savescreenshot "C:\Users\Kishore\Desktop\Screenshot.jpg"
```

using window schedular, you can schedule this bat file in every 10 min. In every 10 min you will get the screenshot saved in your given location folder.

Comment: Probably @lucy-s doesn't want to download any additional software.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done without external tools but you'll need .net frame work (installed by default from vista and above) and [screenCapture.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/screenCapture.bat)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set counter=1
:repeat
ping localhost  -n 1 -w 600000
call screenCapture screen%counter%.jpg jpg
set /a counter=counter+1
goto :repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an improved answer of @npocmaka:

Create the batch file `screenCapture.bat` (https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/screenCapture.bat):

```
// 2>nul||@goto :batch
/*
:batch
@echo off
setlocal

:: find csc.exe
set "csc="
for /r "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\" %%# in ("*csc.exe") do  set "csc=%%#"

if not exist "%csc%" (
   echo no .net framework installed
   exit /b 10
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
   call %csc% /nologo /r:"Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" || (
      exit /b %errorlevel% 
   )
)
%~n0.exe %*
endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

// reference  
// https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/eeff544a-f690-4f6b-a586-11eea6fc5eb8

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;


/// Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file. 

public class ScreenCapture
{

    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot the active window 

    public Image CaptureActiveWindow()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(User32.GetForegroundWindow());
    }

    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop 

    public Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
    }

    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window 

    private Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        // get te hDC of the target window 
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
        // get the size 
        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        // create a device context we can copy to 
        IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        // create a bitmap we can copy it to, 
        // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height 
        IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
        // select the bitmap object 
        IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        // bitblt over 
        GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
        // restore selection 
        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        // clean up 
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
        // get a .NET image object for it 
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
        // free up the Bitmap object 
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        return img;
    }

    public void CaptureActiveWindowToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureActiveWindow();
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }

    public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureScreen();
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }

    static bool fullscreen = true;
    static String file = "screenshot.bmp";
    static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp;
    static String windowTitle = "";

    static void parseArguments()
    {
        String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (arguments.Length == 1)
        {
            printHelp();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        if (arguments[1].ToLower().Equals("/h") || arguments[1].ToLower().Equals("/help"))
        {
            printHelp();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        file = arguments[1];
        Dictionary<String, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat> formats =
        new Dictionary<String, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat>();

        formats.Add("bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        formats.Add("emf", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf);
        formats.Add("exif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Exif);
        formats.Add("jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        formats.Add("jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        formats.Add("gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        formats.Add("png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        formats.Add("tiff", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
        formats.Add("wmf", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf);


        String ext = "";
        if (file.LastIndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            ext = file.ToLower().Substring(file.LastIndexOf('.') + 1, file.Length - file.LastIndexOf('.') - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid file name - no extension");
            Environment.Exit(7);
        }

        try
        {
            format = formats[ext];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Probably wrong file format:" + ext);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Environment.Exit(8);
        }


        if (arguments.Length > 2)
        {
            windowTitle = arguments[2];
            fullscreen = false;
        }

    }

    static void printHelp()
    {
        //clears the extension from the script name
        String scriptName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
        scriptName = scriptName.Substring(0, scriptName.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(scriptName + " captures the screen or the active window and saves it to a file.");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Usage:");
        Console.WriteLine(" " + scriptName + " filename  [WindowTitle]");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("filename - the file where the screen capture will be saved");
        Console.WriteLine("     allowed file extensions are - Bmp,Emf,Exif,Gif,Icon,Jpeg,Png,Tiff,Wmf.");
        Console.WriteLine("WindowTitle - instead of capture whole screen you can point to a window ");
        Console.WriteLine("     with a title which will put on focus and captuted.");
        Console.WriteLine("     For WindowTitle you can pass only the first few characters.");
        Console.WriteLine("     If don't want to change the current active window pass only \"\"");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        User32.SetProcessDPIAware();
        
        parseArguments();
        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        if (!fullscreen && !windowTitle.Equals(""))
        {
            try
            {

                Interaction.AppActivate(windowTitle);
                Console.WriteLine("setting " + windowTitle + " on focus");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Probably there's no window like " + windowTitle);
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Environment.Exit(9);
            }


        }
        try
        {
            if (fullscreen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Taking a capture of the whole screen to " + file);
                sc.CaptureScreenToFile(file, format);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Taking a capture of the active window to " + file);
                sc.CaptureActiveWindowToFile(file, format);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check if file path is valid " + file);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions 

    private class GDI32
    {

        public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter 
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
          int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
          int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
          int nHeight);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
    }


    /// Helper class containing User32 API functions 

    private class User32
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetProcessDPIAware();
    }
}
```

Use another batch file `call_screenCapture.bat` to call it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set counter=1
:repeat
ping localhost  -n 1 -w 600000
call screenCapture screen%counter%.jpg "window name"
set /a counter=counter+1
goto :repeat
```

The `window name` must the be one that appears in Task manager once the process tree is expanded, that is the window name and not the program name (which is usually in the top level), for example here we have to give the name of the Excel window which corresponds to the open file:

```
call screenCapture screen%counter%.jpg "Sales.xlsx - Excel"
```

[image: Expanding Microsoft Excel window in Task Manager]

If the Window name has weird characters or spaces, the window name may be difficult to grasp, so with PowerShell they can be listed:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | Format-Table Id, Name, mainWindowtitle -AutoSize

   Id Name                 MainWindowTitle
   -- ----                 ---------------
11920 Notepad              screenCapture.bat: Notepad
20848 Notepad              call_screenCapture.bat: Notepad    
19376 EXCEL                Sales.xlsx - Excel
23096 WindowsTerminal      Windows PowerShell
```

Be aware that the chosen window will be set active (will come to front and stay there) in order for the screenshot to be taken. If you don't want this to happen find another way.